# What WPF controls should I use for my application?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, controls

First off, I am somewhat familiar with Windows Forms but new to WPF.  I have a main window divided into three sections that I'm currently implementing as pages.

The first is a queue of individual strings in a fixed size viewing area.  When a new string is added at the "top", the one at the "bottom" disappears, creating a scrolling effect.  [Here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEIWZ.png).

The second looks essentially like a grid with 9 columns and about 15 rows.  It really is a three groups of three columns that wrap text content.  For instance when the first section fills up, the next data element is added to the first row of the second section. [Here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ADFH.png)

The third is simply a text ticker scrolling left to right.

I'd appreciate any insight.  I'd consider any third party controls as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Define add at top?  You want data to go out of view or actually go away?  Is the middle one data source or 3?   Define text ticker?   This is really 3 questions that all need better definition.

Comment: 1) Add at top, meaning a new element is brought into the field of view at the top row of the column.  2) When this happens, the row at the bottom both leaves the field of view and the data is discarded.  3) The middle one is not connected to a database.  It grows/shrinks in real time.  4) It's a static string that comes into view at one side of the screen and gradually moves to the other side of the screen.  This is looped.  It works like a [stock ticker](http://www.mediabistro.com/prnewser/files/2011/03/stock-ticker1.jpg).  I know I can do this using a Label on a Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You could use a simple [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) for this.

2) You could probably bend the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) to your will.

Comment: Thanks.  That was more or less my first thought.  I wanted to check to see if there are WPF controls that had some of the functionality I need "built in" before I do it myself.

Comment: No I know, but I was still fishing for some other options.  Specifically, third party controls that are standard replacements for the native ListBox and DataGrid that fits my needs.